# Powershell for O365 GUI: permissions

Tags: powershell, office365

**Background:**

It seems someone has set user-mailbox permissions [using the O365 GUI](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user-in-office-365-admin-help-1dbcf12f-a9de-4d1d-b0b3-a227f8a736d8) (**not** exchange online GUI):

**Issue:**

This means I can't use the normal exchange-powershell method to check mailbox permissions... like we can if set using Exchange Online Admin Center GUI or `Add-MailboxPermission`:

```
Import-PSSession ( New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -Credential (Get-Credential myname@myco.com ) )
Get-MailboxPermission SharedUser@myco.com
```

^^ This does not return the permissions set in O365 GUI. Only Exchange Online.

**Question:**

What is the correct commandlet to manage the permissions set [using the O365 GUI](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user-in-office-365-admin-help-1dbcf12f-a9de-4d1d-b0b3-a227f8a736d8) ?

**Previous work:**

I have tried looking at the [MSOL-User commandlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell) also, as these seem to use O365 rather than exchange online... but [they don't have one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0) relating to permissions.

Also I have previously checked `mailboxfolderpermission`.

**More Clarifications:**

StaffMember@myco.com can see SharedUser@myco.com's mailbox in outlook.
This is also represented in:
 [Office 365 control panel / GUI](https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home#/users) > Users > SharedUser > Mail Settings > Mailbox Permissions
These permissions do NOT seem to show in [Exchange Admin Center](https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/?rfr=Admin_o365&exsvurl=1&mkt=en-US&Realm=myco.com) or exchange powershell.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of O365 Portal, EAC and what you enter in PowerShell and what you receive? Of course hide the sensitive data but in the way that we can distinguish shareduser from staffmember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of permissions you can set over the mailbox: `FullAccess`, `SendAs` and `SendOnBehalf`. Each of them can be checked/managed using different cmdlets:

- `FullAccess` (*Read and manage* in O365 GUI) can be viewed using [`Get-MailboxPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps) and managed using [`Add-MailboxPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps)/[`Remove-MailboxPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/remove-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps)
- `SendAs` can be viewed using [`Get-RecipientPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-recipientpermission?view=exchange-ps) and managed using [`Add-RecipientPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-recipientpermission?view=exchange-ps)/[`Remove-RecipientPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/remove-recipientpermission?view=exchange-ps)
- `SendOnBehalf` can be viewed using [`Get-Mailbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) and managed using[`Set-Mailbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) (parameter `GrantSendOnBehalfTo`)

---

Clarifying the question from comments:

> Unfortunately `Get-RecipientPermission` says "applied to: Exchange online" and I am specifically talking about Office365 which seems to be a different set of cmdlets. Other-User had full access to shared-user's mailbox, yet `Get-MailboxPermission shared-user` showed nothing about the Other-User.

The fact that permissions can be set via O365 portal doesn't mean that the permissions are not set in Exchange Online. Office 365 user objects (the ones you can access via `Get-MsolUser`) cannot have FullAccess/SendAs/SendOnBehalf set on them, only mailboxes can have them.

When you set the permission (let's say you add *Read and manage* over `shared-user` to `other-user`) via **O365 portal**, the change should reflect on the **Exchange Admin Center** (when you check `shared-user` you'll see `other-user` in *Full Access* field) and in **`Get-MailboxPermission shared-user`**. Not sure what happened that you haven't seen these permissions but check these three first. It might be some delay in synchronization too.

Comment: Thankyou for clarifying the GUI permissions that was a good read. Unfortunately `Get-RecipientPermission` says "applied to: Exchange online" and I am specifically talking about Office365 which seems to be a different set of cmdlets.
Other-User had full access to shared-user's mailbox, yet `Get-MailboxPermission shared-user` showed nothing about the Other-User.

Comment: @Hicsy I added the explanation based on the comment.